# A question about boundedness, continuity, and integrability

Tags: continuity

[image: Question and answers]

Didn't include my drafting but not sure if my answer is right.

Comment: Just a heads up: this question might not be received very well by the community since you haven't typed your question using MathJax and you haven't shown any of your work. The community at large generally responds positively to questions that also include explanations of how you arrived at your answer(s).

Comment: In e) I think it should be $a>-2$. Otherwise I don't see problems.

Comment: @Jakobian Riemann integrable implies bounded

Comment: Agreed. When we talk about the usual definition. I was thinking more in the terms of improper integrals.

Comment: @Jakobian In e), could you please explain why you reached a>-2. Thanks:)

Comment: @Jimmy Like user pointed out, I think you need to use the standard definition of a Riemann integral, not improper integrals. But I might explain how I did it. $\int_0^1 x^a\cos(1/x)\ dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{u^{a-2}}\cos(u)\ du$. From Dirichlet test, the integral is convergent when $a>2$. Otherwise it's obviously divergent.